# Jqwidget Pie chart labels

Tags: charts, jqwidget

How to use the pie chart of jqxChart with custom labels?

This is the main demo:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_pie_series.htm

In the pie I would like to have the description (in the example the Browser name) instead of percentage in the labels. Is it possibile? I found how to set it only for the legend but not in the label inside the pie.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement the Chart's formatFunction which is used for formatting the Labels?

Comment: Yes, but this has only the value (percentage) as parameter and not the label.